# How to graph a series of coupled oscillators and watch the wave move along them

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, animation

Here are the differential equations that set's up the 11 coupled oscillators.

```
new = Join[
Table[x[i]''[t] == - x[i][t] + 
 0.1*(x[i + 1][t] - 2*x[i][t] + x[i - 1][t]), {i, 1, 
9}], {x[0]''[t] == -x[0][t], x[10]''[t] == x[9][t], x[0][0] == 1, 
x[0]'[0] == 1, x[1]'[0] == 0, x[1][0] == 0}, 
Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 2, 10}], Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, 10}]]
```

Here are the solutions.

```
Solt = NDSolve[new, Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}], {t, 25}]
```

Here are the individual plots.

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[x[i][t] /. Solt], {t, 0, 25}, 
PlotRange -> All], {i, 0, 10}]
```

I am trying to figure out how to make a graph so along the x-axis are my i's from 0 to 10, and I can watch the wave move along each oscillator as time moves on. I keep getting errors in which it floods my notebook and doesn't stop unless I close the kernel.

This is what I have so far, and I'm not sure how to incorporate time into this.

```
Plot[Evaluate[x[i][t] /. Solt], {i, 0, 10}]
```

EDIT Coupled in a circle

```
Stew = Join[
 Table[x[i]''[t] == - x[i][t] + 
  0.1*(x[i + 1][t] - 2*x[i][t] + x[i - 1][t]), {i, 1, 
 9}], {x[10]''[t] == - x[10][t] + 
  0.1*(x[0][t] - 2*x[10][t] + x[9][t]), 
x[0]''[t] == - x[0][t] + 
  0.1*(x[1][t] - 2*x[0][t] + x[10][t])}, {x[0][0] == 0, 
x[0]'[0] == 0, x[1][0] == 1, x[1]'[0] == 0.5}, 
Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 2, 10}], Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 2, 10}]];
```

The Dsolve

```
Loin = NDSolve[Stew, Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}], {t, 6.28}]
```

The individual graphs

```
Table[Plot[Evaluate[x[i][t] /. Loin], {t, 0, 6.28}, 
PlotRange -> All], {i, 0, 10}]
```

How would I go about putting the i=0 to 10 around in a circle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**After edit**

I think oscillation directions should be parallel.

```
g[t_] = Table[{Cos[i*2 Pi/11], Sin[i*2 Pi/11], x[i][t]} /. Loin[[1]], {i, 0, 10}]; 

Animate[
 Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[g[t], PlotRange -> 1.5, BoxRatios -> 1, Filling -> Axis,
            PlotStyle -> Directive@AbsolutePointSize@7, Boxed -> False],
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos@t, Sin@t, 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}]
  ,
  ImageSize -> 500, ViewVector -> {{Cos[t/15], Sin[t/15], 1} 11, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> None, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
  SphericalRegion -> True],
  {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

**Before edit**

```
f[t_] = Table[{i, x[i][t]} /. Solt[[1]], {i, 0, 10}];

Animate[ 
 ListPlot[f[t], PlotRange -> {{0, 11}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
 , {t, 0, 25}
 ]
```

Good to notice: In `f[t]` definition `:=` is intentionally replaced by `=`.

[image]

Comment: wow that's fantastic!!!!

Comment: I may be making another question where I couple the last point to the first point. I would then want to make the same type if thing, but take the i's and put them around in a circle. so that the 10 is equal to the 0. I already have all the individual plots of this, I would just need some guidance to how to put them in a circle instead of a line.

Comment: @James Edit this question. Put new code and questions here. I think there is no need to make another. May be You could also analyze this solution and answer Your own question. Tip: `Table[{Cos[i*2Pi/11],Sin[i*2Pi/11],x[i][t]},{i,0,10}]`

Comment: Hmm. let me see if I can come up with something

Comment: Would I have to use a parametric plot?

Comment: @James `ListPointPlot3D` or `Graphics3D` also will be good. Of course arguments for each method should look slightly different.

Comment: My computer keeps freezing when I try the 3d plotting.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I Got this...I don't know what to put for the i's. I need 3 parameters?
    Animate[pts = 
  Table[{Cos[i*2 Pi/11], Sin[i*2 Pi/11], x[i][t]}, {i, 0, 10, 10}]; 
 ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotRange -> {{- 6, 6}, {- 6, 6}, {-2, 2}}], {t,
   0, 6.28}, AnimationRate -> 3, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]

Comment: , How would you stop the axis from rotating?

Comment: @James `VectorView` is t-dependent: `ViewVector -> {{Cos[t/15], Sin[t/15], 1}` just set it to {1,1,1} or delete it.

Comment: I did that before I asked you, and it didn't work. Then I tried it again after you told me to, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Solution by @Kuba can be easily extended to put the oscillators on a circle.

```
Loin = NDSolve[Stew, Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}], {t, 50}];

fr[t_] = Transpose@{Most@Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/11], x[#][t]&/@Range[0, 10]} /. First@Loin;

r0 = 3;
Animate[
   ListPlot[
      Function[{th, r}, {(r0 + r) Cos[th], (r0 + r) Sin[th]}] @@@ fr[t], 
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      Prolog -> {Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 3]}, Axes -> False, 
      PlotMarkers -> Automatic], 
  {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: That isn't working for me.

And I wanted the 2nd edited part of the equation to be in a circle because they are all connected.

Comment: So replace the `Solt` with `Loin`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.