# How to Rotate a 3DPlot with a dynamic controller and export in .gif or .avi?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, dynamic, rotation, gif-format

I would like to have the following `3DPlot` to `Rotate` around a vertical axis defined within the `3DPlot` itself: in particular, I would like the box not to change size during the rotation. I was trying with `Graphics3D` but then I encountered issues to keep `PlotLegends`. I'm having issues to combine `Show`, `Plot3D` `Rotate`and `Graphics3D` to get my goal. Finally, I would like this rotation to occur dynamically with a controller and have as an output an animated .gif or .avi. Of course the Legend shouldn't rotate. Some hints were given here:
[How to rotate around z-axis a simple 3DPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145494/how-to-rotate-around-z-axis-a-simple-3dplot/145497#145497)
but in that case I am rotating the 3DPlot and not the whole `Graphics3D`.

[image]

```
 vectorbeta = 
 Sort[{0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000}];
 Edistr = Table[
 1/(i)  Abs[(1 - (1 - I)/2 Sqrt[i/2] Cosh[(1 - I) Sqrt[i/2] z]/
       Sinh[(1 - I)/2 Sqrt[i/2]]) dW[x]/dW1]^2, {i, vectorbeta}];
 Show[Flatten[{Table[
Plot3D[Edistr[[i]], {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1/2, 1/2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][i], 
 PlotLegends -> {Row[{"beta=", 
     ToString[
      If[Element[vectorbeta[[i]], Integers] == True, 
        Rationalize[vectorbeta[[i]]], N[vectorbeta[[i]], 3]] If[
        vectorbeta[[i]] == 37, "(max dissipation)", 
        Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]]}]}], {i, 1, Length[Edistr]}]}], 
        ImageSize -> Large, 
         AxesLabel -> {"x","z"}, 
        PlotLabel -> 
        "Normalized distribution of rate of energy dissipation W in the on-
        axis case", 
        AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

Comment: Is this what you need? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46355/5478

Comment: Another related: [26987](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26987/5478), Let me know if they provide enough help or is there anything to clarify.

Comment: Here is a link about export part: [27202](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/5478)