# Position of axes labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a 2D parametric plot like the following:

```
ParametricPlot[
  {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π},
  Frame -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], PlotRangePadding -> 0.2
]
```

[image: wrong labels]

But I would like the axes labels `x, y` to be positioned besides the arrowheads (i.e. `y` left of the vertical arrowhead and `x` just below the horizontal one).

Since I can't use the frame as a replacement for the axes (as the axes are in the middle, not at the edge), I believe I cannot use the approach suggested in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17747/7508).

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could "abuse" [`Arrowheads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) for this purpose; it has the advantage of tracking the axes wherever they may roam.  Here is a utility function `toArrowheads`:

```
toArrowheads[{x_, y_}, head_, size_: 0.015, xos_: {-3, -3}, yos_: {-3, 3}] := 
  {Arrowheads[{{size, 1, Graphics[{head, Inset[x, xos]}]}}], 
   Arrowheads[{{size, 1, Graphics[{head, Inset[y ~Rotate~ (-90 °), yos]}]}}]}
```

The first parameter is a list with supplemental "x" and "y" labels which may be arbitrary expressions.  The second parameter is the base arrowhead graphic.  The next three parameters are optional and control the size of the arrowhead and the offset of the "x" and "y" labels.

In use:

```
head = Polygon[{{-3, 1}, {0, 0}, {-3, -1}, {-2.2, 0}}];

ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π},
  Frame -> True,
  AxesStyle -> toArrowheads[Style[#, 20] & /@ {"x", "y"}, head],
  PlotRangePadding -> 0.2,
  PlotRange -> {-0.8, 1.2},
  AxesOrigin -> {-0.1, 0.3}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I had the same idea but I didn't know how to attach the label to Arrowhead. This time I've missed "Details and Options" :)

Comment: works great, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I really like your method too, but I have an issue since I'm trying to use it to put labels either in the inside or in the outside of the plot area. When I put them outside (i.e. positive x offset), sometimes the labels appear "cut", since there is no extra room allocated for them (as is when using `AxesLabel`). Do you think this can be easily addressed? I've been trying to add some extra space putting things like `Spacer` in `AxesLabel` in addition to this, but things get messy quickly, and am finding hard to fit it neatly since `AxesLabel` offsetting doesn't appear consistent.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `Epilog` to put the labels there manually:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], PlotRangePadding -> 0.2, 
    Epilog -> {Inset["x", Scaled[{0.95, 0.48}]], Inset["y", Scaled[{0.48, 0.95}]]}]
```

I used `Scaled` so it doesn't matter how large the circle is (and works well with `PlotRangePadding`).

[image]

**Asymmetrical Version - not yet profoundly tested**

Based on Mr. Wizards comments, I thought about asymmetrical ideas. He showed how to "abuse" the arrowheads - I'll try something different here (note that the code can be optimized, but I keep it rather extensive to show what I was thinking):

What I do: I get the `PlotRange`, `AxesOrigin` and `PlotRangePadding` and calculate the position:

```
doPP[pp_] :=
   Module[{plotRange, plotRangePadding, axes, offset},
     plotRange = Extract[pp, Most /@ Position[pp, PlotRange]][[1, 2]];
     plotRangePadding = {-Abs@#, Abs@#} &@
        Extract[pp, Most /@ Position[pp,   PlotRangePadding]][[1, 2]];
     axes = Reverse@Extract[pp, Most /@ Position[pp, AxesOrigin]][[1, 2]];
     offset = 
        Rescale[#1, #2] & @@@ Transpose[{axes, plotRangePadding + # & /@ plotRange}];
     Show[pp, 
        Epilog -> {Inset["x", Scaled[{ 0.95, offset[[1]] - 0.02}]], 
                   Inset["y", Scaled[{offset[[2]] - 0.02, 0.95}]]}]]
```

where you can customize `0.02` and `0.95` to your liking (or set as options, parameters).

We can execute now:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], PlotRangePadding -> 0.2, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0.3, 0.5}, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 1.3}] // doPP
```

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps address positioning with non-centered axes from either e.g. `AxesOrigin -> {-0.3, 0.5}` or `PlotRange -> {-0.2, 1.3}`?  (+1 of course)

Comment: 3D variation http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27004/5478

Comment: thanks for the input, @Mr.Wizard! You make it sound like there is an obvious/easy way to do it... I tried something, see my edited answer. If there is something smarter, feel free to add/edit/new-answer :)

Comment: @Pinguin No, nothing easy or obvious that I could think of; I gave my own method below.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: ok cool, I like your approach - my idea (should it prove to be stable) works without arrowheads, at least one advantage...

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way, based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-to-get-the-real-plotrange-of-graphics-with-geometrictransformations-in-it/18040#18040) by [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280).  It is a little slower than the others due to `Rasterize`, but it handles asymmetrical axes positions.  One could also use [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Offset.html) instead of `{3.5, 2.}` to handle offsetting the labels, or make the offsets arguments to `labelaxes`.

```
labelaxes[plot_, {xlabel_, ylabel_}] := 
 Module[{xlim, ylim, orig}, 
  Rasterize[
   Show[plot, Frame -> False, Ticks -> {(xlim = {##}) &, (ylim = {##}) &}], 
   ImageResolution -> 1];
  orig = AxesOrigin /. AbsoluteOptions[plot, AxesOrigin];
  Show[plot,
   Graphics[{
     Text[TraditionalForm[xlabel], {xlim[[2]], orig[[2]]}, {3.5, 2.}], 
     Text[TraditionalForm[ylabel], {orig[[1]], ylim[[2]]}, {3.5, 2.}]}]
   ]
  ]


labelaxes[
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]} + {0.1, 0.2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  Frame -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], PlotRangePadding -> 0.2], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I suppress the frame so that the axes will be shown:

```
labelaxes[
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]} + {2, 4}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  (*Frame -> True,*) AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], PlotRangePadding -> 0.2], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `PlotLegends` + `Placed` to place the axes labels:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[Style[x, FontSize->Scaled@.05, Italic, Bold], Scaled@{.97, .46}],
  Placed[Style[y, FontSize -> Scaled[.05], Italic, Bold], Scaled@{.46, .97}]}, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04],  PlotRangePadding -> 0.2]
```

[image]