# How to change the position of axes label?

Tags: plotting

How to change the position of axes label such that the label of the vertical axes appears at the bottom and the label of the horizontal axis appear in the left?

```
ParametricPlot[{4 Cos[θ] - 2 Sin[θ]^2, 
  3 Sin[θ] + 2 Cos[θ]^2}, {θ, 2.1, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Dashed, Black}}, Frame -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Q/k", "N/k"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `FrameLabel -> {"N/k", "Q/k"}`.

Answer (score 6):

As [Anjan Kumar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19742/anjan-kumar) comments the direct solution is to use [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html) instead:

```
ParametricPlot[{4 Cos[θ] - 2 Sin[θ]^2, 3 Sin[θ] + 2 Cos[θ]^2}, {θ, 2.1, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Dashed, Black}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"N/k", "Q/k"}]
```

[image]

Supposing that feature were absent you could use [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) instead:

```
ParametricPlot[{4 Cos[θ] - 2 Sin[θ]^2, 3 Sin[θ] + 2 Cos[θ]^2}, {θ, 2.1, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thin, Dashed, Black}}, Frame -> True];

Labeled[%, {"Q/k", "N/k"}, {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

See also:

- [Placing x-axes label below rather than at end of axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17747/121)
- [Position of axes labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31764/121)
- [Positioning axes labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87388/121)

(your question likely duplicates one of these and your question should probably be closed as such)