# RotateLabel is not working in Plot

Tags: plotting, labeling, rotation

I want to generate a plot with the label of the vertical axis rotated by 90 degree in order to save space. I cannot make that work with the option **RotateLabel**. Here is a MWE:

```
Graphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}], RotateLabel -> True]
```

According to the Mathematica documentation **RotateLabel** is a **Graphics** option that should also be working with **Plot** or **ListPlot**.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I always thought that this option is automatically used in the funcltions like `Plot` if the option `Frame->True` is used. So the label is rotated by default, but if it should not be rotated, use `RotateLabel->False`.

Comment: I'd use `AxesLabel -> {"x", Rotate["y", Pi/2]}`.

Answer (score 1):

[`RotateLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateLabel.html) is exclusively for `Frame`, not for `Axes`.

As a workaround, you can rotate any piece of text using [`Rotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html) before rendering it.

Comment: Thanks. This only rotates the text, but I would also like to place the label besides the y-axis, not above it.

Comment: @benybenjamin Then the best solution is to use a `Frame`. Note that you can turn on and off the four frame borders independently.  You can keep only the left and bottom ones for an  axes-like look.

Comment: @benybenjamin Sorry, I just noticed that you already found it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87389/11279).

This works for my example:

`Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}, Axes -> False, 
Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
FrameLabel -> {{"a very long label for the y-axis", None}, {"x", None}}, FrameTicks -> All]`

Thanks.