# RotateLabel doesn't work?

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling

**Bug introduced after 12.0.0 and persisting through 13.2.0 or later**

I'm creating a really simple plot with the code attached below. However the y-axis label is rotated and parallel to the y-axis by default. I'd like to rotate it by 90 degrees but it doesn't seem to work. I found some related posts such as [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173154/rotatelabel-is-not-working-in-plot) but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I tried setting RotateLabel to True or False but neither does anything. Does anyone know what I did wrong? Many thanks.

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[{impData[[7, All, {1, 5}]]},
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
   PlotMarkers -> None,
   AxesLabel -> " ",
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {{"alpha^2", None}, {"alpha", None} },
   RotateLabel -> False,
   LabelStyle -> {20},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-100, 500}},
   PlotStyle -> {},
   ImageSize -> Large];
Show[p1]
```

Comment: `impData` is left undefined. Could you give a toy-model set of data? Many thanks

Comment: @bmf It does not work with any data e.g. `RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi works fine on my machine. I am trying on `V13.0.0` now

Comment: Final comment: works as expected on `V12.0.0 ` and it does not work properly on `V13.0.0 `

Comment: Recommendation:  pare your code down to the *MINIMAL* example that illustrates your problem.  Why do you define `p1`, the `Show` it?  (No reason.)  Why do you define `ImageSize -> Large`?  (No reason.)  Why do you define `AxesLabel -> ""`. (No reason.)  Why do you define `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`?  (No reason.)  Why is your undefined data list set with indices? 
 (No reason.)  Why do you... well... get the idea?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this question and what's the reason behind it. The command runs perfectly on an earlier version and the there's indeed a puzzling situation that needs a workaround - at least I was not able to resolve it differently. And finally, the author of the OP has presented a very clean code that illustrates the problem

Comment: @bmf:  Clean code?  Really?  Can't the code be reduced by, oh, 50% minimum?  (See solution, below.)  You explain why we define `p1` then separately `Show` it... to take one of many examples.  And what about impData?  and... and...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The fact that the code has redundancies **DOES NOT** mean -at least for me- that it is not clean enough. In my eyes, the phrasing of the question is good. It describes a problematic situation that you obtain in versions later than `V12.0.0`. It has a working piece of code. The only thing that is missing is the set of data. Since you have a 5-digit reputation it should not be that difficult to come up with a toy-model set of data, and I am not being sassy or disrespectful. This is my honest opinion. In the sense that I was able to do it; below 3000.

Comment: *My* honest opinion is that the code is extremely bloated (i.e., not "clean"), as it distracts readers with numerous irrelevancies.  A reader has to wonder:  "Does it matter that the plot is created in full, and then in a separate line presented with `Show`?"  Moreover, you are factually incorrect when you refer to the irrelevancies as "redundancies."  They are the *opposite* of redundancies.  Note I never complained the code "didn't work" (and wonder why you even brought up that issue).  I'm teaching a *Mathematica*-based course at university next year and I will mark down such bloated code.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I just saw your comment. Evidently we have different opinions on the matter. I do not consider it to a bad thing, and I only meant to understand your comments, that's all. Enjoy your lectures and best of luck to your future endeavors

Comment: a work-around: use `Show` with the option `RotateLabel -> False`: i.e., `Show[p1, RotateLabel -> False]`.

Answer (score 5):

[`Rotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html) the label by `-Pi/2` to cancel the undesired rotation.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

data = Sort@Table[
    {RandomReal[1000], RandomReal[500]},
    10];

p1 = ListLinePlot[data,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {
    {Rotate[HoldForm[alpha^2], -Pi/2], None}, {HoldForm@alpha, None}},
  LabelStyle -> {16},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-100, 500}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nicely done! Out of curiosity, and because the version is not mentioned in the OP, were you able to verify the behavior described in the question in `V13.0.1`?

Comment: @bmf - yes, the problem exists in v13.0.1 on a Mac

Comment: Many thanks. Does this qualify as a bug? Since on `V12.0.0` works as expected? I'm not quite sure

Comment: @bmf - yes it is a bug. It apparently was introduced some time after v12.0.0

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Would you like to update the OP as well?

Comment: @bmf - I don't understand what update you think is necessary. The OP will get notified of any comment on this page.

Comment: I meant the `bug` tag and the version after which it started and though which it persists. Not sure if it's necessary or not.

Answer (score 4):

Another work around that seems less kludgy: Use `Show[p1,... RotateLabel -> False]`. The `List*Plot` function must fumble the `RotateLabel` option.

```
Show[
 ListLinewPlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", AxesLabel -> " ", 
  LabelStyle -> {20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-100, 500}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {}],
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"alpha^2", None}, {"alpha", None}}, 
 RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

The bug also arises in `ListPlot`, `ListLogPlot`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am on `V13.0.0`

This is a peculiar behavior of [`ListLinePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) as far as I can tell. If I try the example from the [`docs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateLabel.html) it works fine.

---

### **Suggesting a workaround using [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)**

---

With

```
impData = {RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100], RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 100]};
```

We do

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[impData,
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
   PlotMarkers -> None,
   AxesLabel -> " ",
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {"alpha", "alpha^2"},
   RotateLabel -> {False, False},
   LabelStyle -> {20},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotStyle -> {},
   ImageSize -> Large];
```

And then

```
Show[Graphics@p1, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
 PlotMarkers -> None,
 AxesLabel -> " ",
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"alpha", "alpha^2"},
 RotateLabel -> False,
 LabelStyle -> {20},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotStyle -> {},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

to get

> [image: desiredoutput]

---

### **On Version 12.0.0 there's no problem**

> [image: bug?]

---