# How can I plot the typical axis and not the "box axis" in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Are there any option to plot the typical and classic axis instead de "box axis" that is the default option in Mathematica?

What I would like is any similar to the axis in red in the following image.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 u, 2 v, u - v}, {u, -16, 16}, {v, -16, 16}, 
 PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}, ImageSize -> Large,
  ViewPoint -> {11, 2, 3}, AxesStyle -> Thick
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please attach code in your original post. It would allow others use what you've already got to produce a solution reflecting on native conventions and observed knowledge of MMA. P.S I do realise there is code in the picture that you've attached.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic ok, thank you and excuse me.

Comment: labeling: [**26979**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26979/5478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Boxed->False` and `AxesOrigin->{0,0,0}`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{2 u, 2 v, u - v}, {u, -16, 16}, {v, -16, 16}, 
 PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 LabelStyle -> {20, Bold},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 ViewPoint -> {11, 2, 3},
 AxesStyle -> Thick,
 Boxed -> False,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
 ]
```

Comment: thank you and excuse me for not posting the code example.

Comment: is easy put the name of the axis in other point?, avoiding be in the middle. for example close to the end of the visible axis, similar to the image of the example in red.

Comment: @MikaIke see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31764/27539 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26979/27539 and links therein