# How to correct the name of axis?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

In the output of a code I can view that the same axe has two names "z" and "x".

How could I correct this?

The code is

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{0*v, 0*v, 0*v}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> {11, 2, 3}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

I think a solution to clarify the image is put the names of axis in the extreme of the axis. If the trouble is because the proximity of the names of axis.

Comment: The problem is that axis labels for 3D graphics are placed near the centre of the axis. In fact in your plot the axis running from left to right that "z" and "x" both appear to be sitting on, is the y axis. You can see this by adding `AxesStyle -> {Red,Green,Blue}` to the options.

Comment: ok, @SimonWoods I found one solution, with no labels and adding inside a multiple graph

     Graphics3D[Text[Style["x", 18, Bold], {rtop*0.88, 0, 0}]],
     Graphics3D[Text[Style["y", 18, Bold], {0, rtop*0.88, 0}]],
     Graphics3D[Text[Style["z", 18, Bold], {0, 0, rtop*0.88}]],

Comment: same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6185820

Comment: related : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26979/5467

Answer (score 4):

I would use `Show` and put the labels as separate graphics:

```
m = 9; (*plot range*)
labels = {Text[Style["X", 16], {1.2 m, 0, 0}], 
  Text[Style["Y", 16], {0, 1.2 m, 0}], Text[Style["Z", 16], {0, 0, 1.2 m}]};

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{0*v, 0*v, 0*v}, {v, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> {-m, m},
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]},
  AxesLabel -> None,
  LabelStyle -> {20, Bold},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  ViewPoint -> {11, 2, 3},
  Boxed -> False,
  PreserveImageOptions -> False,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}],
 Graphics3D[labels]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{}, {v, 0, 1},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
 BaseStyle -> {Gray, 20, Bold},
 Boxed -> False,
 Epilog -> {Text["X", {.95, .5}], Text["Y", {0.4, 0.35}], Text["Z", {.5, .95}],},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> {-9, 9},
 ViewPoint -> {11, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `ViewPoint`. Here I use `ViewPoint -> {5, 10, 4}`

[image]

To be safe, you can avoid the `Viewpoint`. Plot it, then rotate it to get the best view, and then use File>Save Selection As or Right click > Save Graphic As to save the image.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, with no labels and adding inside a multiple graph

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{0*v, 0*v, 0*v}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, LabelStyle -> {20, Bold}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> {11, 2, 3}, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
 , Graphics3D[Text[Style["x", 18, Bold], {rtop*0.88, 0, 0}]], 
 Graphics3D[Text[Style["y", 18, Bold], {0, rtop*0.88, 0}]], 
 Graphics3D[Text[Style["z", 18, Bold], {0, 0, rtop*0.88}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you would want to drop the `AxesLabel` so as to avoid duplicate labels.